# Выбор варианта из перечня возможных ответов в Python, как использовать if и elif

Tags: python

Изучаю азы Python, пытаюсь написать простенький текстовый квест. Намертво застрял в следующем моменте: допустим, есть реплика персонажа и тебе нужно выбрать один из нескольких вариантов ответа. В зависимости от твоего выбора, персонаж выдаст тебе следующую реплику.

Пример:
"Вася, как твои дела"?

Варианты:
a) Нормально
б) Хорошо
в) Плохо

Выбрали ответ "Нормально", нажав на кнопку 'a' - будет ответ "ну понятно"
Выбрали "Хорошо", нажав на 'b' - будет ответ "ну и замечательно"
Ну и далее по той же логике.

Я понимаю, что это реализуется через операторы выбора, но у меня не выходит.
Кусок из кода:

```
print('Вася, как твои дела?')
print('a)Нормально')
print('b)Хорошо')

input()

a = 'normalno'
b = 'horosho'

if a == 'normalno':
    print('Ну понятно')
elif b == 'horosho':
    print('Ну и замечательно')
```

Пробовал после if поставить else, но это прокатит только в том случае, если есть не больше одного альтернативного варианта.

Первое условие у меня выполняется корректно, второе - никак.

Comment: Обратите внимание на формулировку заголовка (я отредактировал). Слово "список" в Python используется для описания типа `list`, лучше для других вещей его не использовать - путает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас результат `input ()` ничему не присваивается.
А далее проверки идут на истинные вещи, так как вы уже сами написали, чему равны эти переменные (это не нужно писать в общем случае при вашей логике работы программы). Посмотрите, что изменено в коде ниже для корректной работы, задайте вопросы, если есть.

```
print('Вася, как твои дела? Введи букву правильного ответа')
print('a)Нормально')
print('b)Хорошо')

answer = input()

if answer == 'a':
    print('Ну понятно')
elif answer == 'b':
    print('Ну и замечательно')
```

Comment: Сергей, благодарю. Заработало) Как только ни колдовал, а оказалось так просто. Один нубский и уточняющий вопрос: вы из моего кода удалили 2  строки (a = 'normalno' b = 'horosho'). Вы это сделали для лаконичности? Просто мало-ли :)

Comment: Да, для лаконичности. А также, чтобы не сбивали с толку. В больших же программах точно не надо оставлять ненужные вещи - потом не вспомнить будет логику, если нет детального комментария. Будет зря потрачено время. Так как тут логика была просто ошибочной и строки не нужны, то удалил. Это же учебный пример, но так же рекомендую и в будущем действовать.

Comment: Вот теперь я понял. До вашего комментария подумал, что эти 2 строки - не лишние, а нужные (и удалили их только для сокращения кода для наглядности). Сейчас понял, что заменяются они одной переменной "answer". Спасибо за уточнение)

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял следующий код должен Вам помочь:

```
print('Вася, как твои дела?')
print('a)Нормально')
print('b)Хорошо')

response = input('Введи ответ: ')


if response == 'Нормально':
    print('Ну понятно')
elif response == 'Хорошо':
    print('Ну и замечательно')
else:
    print('плохо')
```

Comment: Артём, выше уже помог Сергей, но спасибо за Вашу отзывчивость!

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
print('Вася, как твои дела? (Выбери правильный ответ')
print('1)Нормально')
print('2)Хорошо')
    
ans = input()
    
if ans == '1':
    print('Понятно')
elif ans == '2':
    print('Круто...')
```